# Run the Mechanize::Firefox script in VNC server using Net::SSH::perl?

Tags: perl, ssh, vnc-server, www-mechanize-firefox

I have done the script with `Mechanize::Firefox`. I need to run the script in VNC server. I'm working on ubuntu. I have installed `krdc` software to run the scripts.

Before running the script I'm starting the vnc server by using the following command `vncserver`.

To connect the server via ssh I have using one password for example `sshpassword`. When open the `krdc` software there I'm using the `vncpassword`.

My problem is, I have trying to run the `Mechanize::Firefox` script using `Net::SSH::perl` script it is running but the firefox is not starting. So I cannot crawl the content.

How can I fix this issue.? I don't know from where need to start.

Comment: Iirc WWW::Mechanize::Firefox doesn't start a browser instance. You need to start it yourself. You can try issuing a `firefox &` via SSH.

Comment: @simbabque Ya I tried it but firefox is not starting in ssh. But as the same way I connect the server via `krdc` then type the `firefox &` it is started.

Comment: Maybe because the SSH session is not the one that has the xserver attached. Can you maybe attach through the vnc?

Comment: @simbabque When I'm starting firefox in ssh it is showing `Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays`

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. Hmm. Try using https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::VNC to create the VNC connection with Perl.